# PR pipeline build not being triggered when target branch is merged into source branch in Azure Devops

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a git repo in Azure Devops with a `main` branch and `feature` branches. We use a strategy was follows for releases:

1. Create `feature` branch from `main`
2. Make changes in `feature` branch
3. Merge in any changes that have been pushed to `main` to `feature` branch
4. Test and deploy `feature` branch
5. Merge feature into `main` (via PR)

We have a deployment pipeline in Azure Devops with stages for build, test and deployment. The pipeline is triggered when a PR is created to merge the `feature` branch in the `main` branch. The instance of the pipeline gets cancelled and a new instance triggered when changes are pushed to the `feature` branch whilst the PR is open. This has meant that there is always an up to date pipeline for the PR we can release from and this strategy has been working for over a year.

This is our branch policy for the `main` branch which triggers the pipeline based on a PR with `main` as the target:
[image: Branch Policy]

Recently we have had two instances where the pipeline has not been cancelled and retriggered after changes have been pushed to the `feature` branch. Specifically this has happened when changes from the `main` branch were merged in whilst the PR was ongoing. Releasing from the active pipeline would have caused a version of the service with the changes from the `feature` branch but without the latest changes from `main`. It was necessary to cancel and manually retrigger the pipeline.

I was wondering if this is new behaviour and if it can be circumvented, it is possible that it has always been this way but after hundreds of releases I think we would have come across it before.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior.

When you have a PR between feature and main, the build that is triggered is a merge representation of the two.

So, when the feature branch got updated with the "new" commits from main, it didn't trigger the build again because there was nothing new to check, as this has been checked already in the previous run.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue. After testing, I found the following:

- If I commit in `feature` branch, the pipeline will be triggered. At the same time, I completed the PR merging from `main` branch to `feature` branch. But at this time, the pipeline will not be triggered by the commit from `main` branch.
- If I merge the `main` branch into the `feature` branch after the pipeline is completed: When there are changes in the commit from `main`, the pipeline can be triggered at this time.  When there isn't any change in the commit from `main`, the pipeline will not be triggered.
- If I created new branch `newfeature` based on `feature`. Commit in `feature` branch, the pipeline will be triggered. At the same time, merge from `newfeature` to `feature`, the old run will be canceled and a new run will be trigger by the commit from `newfeature`.

If there is nothing new for `main` branch when merging from `main` branch to `feature` branch, then for the second case I listed, it seems that the pipeline should not be triggered either.

As a workaround, it's suggested that you could merge your `main` branch to `feature` after the pipeline is completed.

I didn’t pay attention to the previous behavior. If merging from `main` branch to `feature` branch previously would cancel the old run and trigger a new run, I suggest you report this issue to the Azure DevOps support on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/report) to confirm if there is any change or it's bug.

Comment: @SBFrancies, have you checked the answer above and whether it's helpful for you? Would you please let me know whether merging from `main` branch to `feature` branch previously would cancel the old run and trigger a new run? If so, I think we can report a bug to the Azure DevOps support.

Comment: apologies for not getting back to you sooner, I am not certain about the previous behaviour but this issue occurred twice in over a short period of time when I hadn't experienced it before in over a year.

Comment: Based on the current situation, it's suggested that you could merge your `main` branch to `feature` after the pipeline is completed as a workaround. Besides, you can also report this issue on Developer Community.